# add replicate value until specific line

Tags: r

My file is look like

> head(df)

```
    V1    V2
1  group     1
2  sc08420_82432 0.000
3 sc08420_159603 0.912
4 sc12525_451180 4.865
5 sc12525_538935 7.156
6 sc12525_402895 9.155
7  group     2
```

so I want to add new column which has value group1 untill the line of group two.
The expeted result is

```
 V1    V2    V3
1  group     1     group1
2  sc08420_82432 0.000  group1
3 sc08420_159603 0.912  group1
4 sc12525_451180 4.865  group1
5 sc12525_538935 7.156  group1
6 sc12525_402895 9.155  group1
7  group     2      group2
```

I have about 17 group so this code is what I try to do

> line_for_group<-grep("group.*",line) ##to find which row contain the word group

```
> for(i in 1:16){ lengthLine[i]<-(line_for_group[i+1]-line_for_group[i])
> } ### to find the number of row to replicate

for(i in 1:16){
result$"V3"[ line_for_group[i]: line_for_group[i+1]]=rep(paste("group",i,sep=""),lengthLine[i])
}
```

However, This code doesn't work. I think R can do in the easy way for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  indx <- df$V1=='group'
  df$V3 <- paste0('group', df$V2[indx][cumsum(indx)])

 df
 #             V1    V2     V3
 #1          group 1.000 group1
 #2  sc08420_82432 0.000 group1
 #3 sc08420_159603 0.912 group1
 #4 sc12525_451180 4.865 group1
 #5 sc12525_538935 7.156 group1
 #6 sc12525_402895 9.155 group1
 #7          group 2.000 group2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("group", "sc08420_82432", "sc08420_159603", 
"sc12525_451180", "sc12525_538935", "sc12525_402895", "group"
), V2 = c(1, 0, 0.912, 4.865, 7.156, 9.155, 2)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: I think you mean `df$V3 <- paste0("group", cumsum(df$V1=='group'))`, because he have more than just two groups

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks, that is better.  If he has more `groups` and the values are not in order, perhaps, needs to check with column `V2` as well.